# Leading and trailing whitespace cut + middle whitespace replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex expression for removing leading and trailing white-spaces and also for replacing all others white-spaces in string. But I don't know how to make this work together.

So, my problem is:

```
string1 " MY FIRST STRING "
```

I want string1 to appear as:

```
"my_first_string".
```

So, I need to remove leading and trailing white-spaces, all other white-spaces needs to be replaced with "_", and the bonus would be to make the string lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) before `preg_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower(trim($str)));
```